# Filter items on list based on its index

Tags: ansible

I have the following variables:

```yaml
total_list: [ node1, node2, node5 ]
desired_cluster_size: 2
```

I need to keep the n<sup>th</sup> first elements in `total_list` based on the integer in variable `desired_cluster_size`. My exepected result is:

```yaml
desired_list : [ node1, node2 ]
```

I have no idea where to start to fulfill this requirement.

Comment: => `desired_list: "{{ total_list[:desired_cluster_size|int] }}"`

Comment: For further readings, search for "list slicing" in your prefered search engine.

Comment: @Zeitounator, maybe you can file an answer based on your comments? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/)

Comment: @U880D I actually voted to close this question as needing more information since there is no evidence of what was already tried.

Answer (score 0):

=> desired_list: "{{ total_list[:desired_cluster_size|int] }}" –

thanks this helped Zeitounator